# Pandas drop() deletes every rows that has same id number

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I have a datameframe like below. I want to drop all grade F's from the dateframe but when I write the code below, It drops all same ID numbers as well. In this case all id number 101 is deleted. but I want to keep only status passed. Only grade F is failed.

`df.drop(df.index[df['Grade'] == 'F'], inplace=True)`

| ID | Lesson | Status | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Math | Passed | A |
| 545 | History | Passed | B |
| 789 | English | Failed | F |
| 101 | History | Failed | F |
| 475 | Math | Passed | C |
| 689 | Enlish | Passed | D |

Comment: Try with groupby and then only drop?

Comment: This happens because you have duplicated indices. Use boolean indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I don't understand what you are trying to do, you can simply do:

```
df2 = df[df['Grade'] != 'F']

df2
ID  Lesson  Status  Grade
0   101 Math    Passed  A
1   545 History Passed  B
4   475 Math    Passed  C
5   689 Enlish  Passed  D
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to just create and use mask, rather than what you are doing i.e. filtering using index and then dropping

```py
>>> df[df.Grade.ne('F')]
      Lesson  Status Grade
ID                        
101     Math  Passed     A
545  History  Passed     B
475     Math  Passed     C
689   Enlish  Passed     D
```